# trying to upgrade a web service to work with new end point 2010

Tags: vb.net, web-services, wsdl, asmx

I have an old web service that is located on a Windows 2003 server and we are getting ready to upgrade the box to Windows 2012. When I regenerate the vb file using the latest wsdl.exe, the new file that is generated does not compile and play well with others, I get hundreds of syntax errors on all "Partial" Classes, I compare the file to the old vb file that was being used and I don't even know if the new one has all the same attributes being called from my legacy program. This program was created originally 10 years ago and if they used an .xsd schema file when generating the final file, I have no idea. Has anyone ran into this issue before? How can I do some forensic work when I don't have any idea how the original vb file got generated? FYI the vb.net program that uses the web service uses it to build menu items based on Reports available and is based on the SSRS ReportServer.

Server Error in '/XXX.Edv.Web' Application.

Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error:

```
Line 288:                    Dim oItemsManagement() As CatalogItem = Application.Item("MANAGEMENTREPORTS")
Line 289:
Line 290:                    If oItemsManagement.Length > 0 Then
Line 291:                        Dim oManagementItem As MenuItem = New MenuItem
Line 292:                        oManagementItem = New MenuItem
```

Comment: Why did you need to run WSDL.EXE again? Why not just change the URL?

Comment: The vb.net program includes the vb file generated and uses it to build a menu

Comment: But why did that need to _change_?

Comment: running wsdl to generate the new web service methods have changed greatly and connecting it to my old app generates thousands of syntax errors

Comment: I am asking you why you needed to run WSDL.EXE a second time? Why not just not run WSDL.EXE at all?

Comment: the vb file that is output by running wsdl.exe is included in my application

Comment: But why change the vb file which is included in your application? Were you simply trying to change the URL of the web service? Because you don't need to change the VB file in order to do that.

Comment: The xml that gets produced by the new ReportService2010.asmx is different than the xml that was generated by the old web service

Comment: This is the first time you have mentioned SSRS 2010! What happens if you make no changes? Any exceptions (post them).